# Calling tableview method within block

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, objective-c-blocks

I have a method which calls a block, and the block then reloads the tableview of the method of the tableviewcontroller reload data.  however the trick is that the block is called inside of a different class.  my question is how do i make it such that when i call [self.tableview reload data] it calls the parent class's function:

```
[pro refreshMatchesWithCallback:^ 
    {
        if ([pro.matches count] > 0) {
        //[self.tableView reloadData];
        NSLog(@"the count of a lifetime is %@", [pro.matches objectAtIndex:0]);
        }
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSNotificationCenter` and set the parent class up as a listener, or you can use a delegate method and fire that off.

Answer (score 0):

So basically the question is more simpler, as the blocks are irrelevant.

The simple question is: How do I execute a method in another controller.
[And the simple answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9731162/312312)