# How to call a method in another class?

Tags: ios, iphone, user-controls, appdelegate

I would like to have only one class for control my menu.
I try used this:

In the .h

```
 #define Generic ((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @interface Generic : UIViewController

 - (IBAction)photo:(id)sender;

 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *apareceMenu;

 @end
```

in the .m

```
- (IBAction)photo:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Ok");

}
```

Now i need read the - (IBAction)photo in other class, But i don't know how.

I believe to be something

```
[Generic photo];
```

Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the instructions in this post:

How to call method from one class in another (iOS) https://stackoverflow.com/a/9731162/2274694

Answer (score 1):

[Generic photo:] is correct method to call the function. Before the you must do this steps in another class.

```
Generic *genericObj = [[Generic alloc]initWithNibName:@"Generic" bundle:nil];
```

then you call your class like,

[genericObj photo];

Answer (score 0):

create object for Generic class and call photo via that object
[genericObj photo];