# How to set CLLocationManager's attribute from other class

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

I am working on a sport project at the moment.
What i want to do is, when users select the AutoPause switch on, the `CLLocationManager` will pause updating location when speed is below a certain level.
Basically, i have figure out how to implement the `locationManager` by changes its attribute, but my question is, how can I set `CLLocationManager`'s attribute from the `settingViewController`, whereas the `CLLocationManager` instance is in another `ViewController`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put the `CLLocationManager` in a singleton ?

Comment: @Larme I have put it in a singleton but I just can't figure out the approach for changing its attribute from another View Controller

Comment: Add a method `-(void)updateLocaltionManagerTargetAttributeSetting:(id)setting`, and do `[[YourSingletonClass sharedManager] updateLocaltionManagerTargetAttributeSetting:something]`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSNotificationCenter` to send notification to enable/ disable the `CLLocationManager`'s autopause attribute in another View Controller.

Other approaches can be:

1. Use class method, it is explained very well in this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9731162/5620628)
2. Use Delegates

Answer (score 0):

idk what' your problem with `CLLocationManager`, do you mean the way to pass object to another view controller? there are several way to do this.[See this question:Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?rq=1)
 I'm pretty sure that you can pass the `CLLocationManager` object to `settingViewController` by setting a property of that `CLLocationManager`,because `passing the object` means pass the reference the object,you can change the object in `settingViewController` life cycle,and it affects the `CLLocationManager` object which created by `ViewController`.

Comment: My problem is, how can i disable/enable CLLocationManager's autopause attribute from View Controller B, as CLLocationManager's instance was inited in View Controller A.

Comment: pass the object to another view controller by setting property would be easy,if you using storyboard for transitions, pass the object by segue.see the article on the link plz.

Comment: Cheers, i think the approach includes pass object and notification, which one do you think is better.